# Apache2: How to split out the SSL configuration?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.2

In Apache2, I'd like to separately define my SSL-related stuff once, and in a separate file from the rest of the configuration. This is mostly a matter of taste, but it also allows me to include the rest of the configuration in my automatic deployment process.

I.e.: current situation:

```
# in file: 0000-ourdomain.com.conf (number needs to be low)
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    # SSL part
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ....crt
    SSLCACertificateFile ...pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile ...intermediate.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ....wildcard.ourdomain.com.key
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ServerName www.ourdomain.com
    ServerAlias ourdomain.com

    # the actual configuration, as found for xx.xx.xx.xx:80, repeated
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like

```
# in file: 0000-ssl-stuff
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    # SSL part
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile ....crt
    SSLCACertificateFile ...pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile ...intermediate.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ....wildcard.ourdomain.com.key
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ServerName www.ourdomain.com
    ServerAlias ourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

# in file: ourdomain.com.conf
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    # the actual configuration, as found for xx.xx.xx.xx:80, repeated
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Apache SSL fails, though it does not give an error message at reload or syntax-check.

My best found workaround is to us an `Include` directive from the 0000-ssl file.

Many thanks!

Comment: what's wrong with the include directive?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate file using the [include directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include). Your 443 vhost would be:

```
# in file: ourdomain.com.conf
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    # the actual configuration, as found for xx.xx.xx.xx:80, repeated
    ServerName www.ourdomain.com
    ServerAlias ourdomain.com

    Include conf/vhosts/ourdomain.ssl.conf
 </VirtualHost>
```

and in conf/vhosts/ourdomain.ssl.conf:

```
# SSL part
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile ....crt
SSLCACertificateFile ...pem
SSLCertificateChainFile ...intermediate.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile ....wildcard.ourdomain.com.key
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

A couple things. First, the include path is relative from the ServerRoot (ie, /usr/local/apache, not relative to the file that included it.

Second, the ourdomain.ssl.conf file does not repeat the VirtualHost directive for xx.xx.xx.xx:443. That's already been handled by the including Vhost.